# Symfony/Doctrine: variations of entities

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Sorry for the vagueness, but I'm confused as to how to describe this database problem. Part of it is a database design problem, the other part is how to efficiently use the Doctrine ORM and Symfony's Form builder engine for this. Let me try to explain:

My database contains repairs for cell phones. Each repair is for one cellphone only. However, some cellphones come in different colours. While some repairs (like battery replacement) are applicable to *all* devices, some (like display replacement) have different prices depending on the colour of the device. It should be possible to, in the `repair` menu, specify the colour of each repair (choose one, many or all).

My current DB design looks like this:

[image: like this?]

But this does not allow me to access the colour of the device from the repair Entity, as here colour has a direct relationship to device, not to repair. So I need a more complex database which still treats the iphone as a single product, but can map various repairs to its many variants *as well as* map universal repairs to *all variants*.

Should I use a join table (repair_device_color) consisting of 3 ids? Seems not pretty. And what's the most efficient way to map this with the Doctrine ORM? Should I use *data inheritance*?

Comment: Hi bluppfisk. I suggest that you get familiar with the [Entity-Relationship Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) for databases, and then draw out a proper ER Diagram - so that you will understand what you need. There is a free [ERMaster plugin](http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/) that you can use in Eclipse (a popular IDE) to create a diagram like this. Thrust me this will help you out.

Comment: Hi Alvin, thanks. In fact I have one, and it consists of a second many-to-many join table, in which device+color are paired with a repair, but I don't know how to map it into Symfony.

Comment: Can you post it somewhere? Maybe use imgur and add the link to your post.

Comment: I took a careful look at your updated diagram bluppfisk. It' ok, but it may be overly too complex for what you might (I'm not certain though) need. Example, you have "devices_colors", but instead this could be a "part" and the "color" of the part can be defined as the color for the particular unique device.

Comment: Do colors map to a "unique" model number? Also, you have a "repairs_parts" table that also connects to the "Part" table; instead of having a repair have an array of parts like in my design. My design is much easier to use. Since you just use a method like `$parts = $repair->getParts();` and that's it, you have all the parts. And this makes everything simple in Twig as well.

Comment: If you mapped it correctly, as I have, I can also do $repair->getParts() and it will give me an array of Part objects. Which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to give you a good answer, so it took me a bit of time to create my answer. This may not be perfect, but it will give you an idea. The digram you gave is not an ER Diagram by the way.

I created this in Excel, and copied and saved as a picture. The table names and ORM annotation are important.

[image: Repairs Schema]

For example you will create an "Device" Entity with the file name as "src/AppBundle/Entity/Device.php" in the standard way. For the arrays, you need to add to a __construct() function in the Entity class.

As an example, this is what the code would look like for the Device Entity:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Device.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="device")
 */
class Device
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="device_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $device_id;

        /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="model", type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $model;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Part", mappedBy="part_device")
     */
    protected $parts = null;

...

    public function __construct(){
        // This is an array of parts.
        $this->parts = new ArrayCollection();

        // Create the other arrays too.
        $this->repairs = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->customers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /*
     * This should automatically be generated by the command.
     * php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Device
     */
    public function addPart($part){
        $this->parts[] = $part;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can figure out the rest. But I think this is a good start.

Comment: Darn, you just edited your diagram. That looks better than the other one.

Comment: Hey Alvin, thanks for the extensive answer. However, the problem is not that I'm unable to make relations between entities. It's more that I need a device to be identified by both its name and its colour (which in itself is a many-to-many, as a device may have a number of colours), in order to match with the correct repairs.

I think I may be on to something with composite keys now.. but still unsure how it's done.

Comment: Question: Do the phones with different colors have "unique" model numbers? I'm just wondering how does the Manufacturer identify them with different colors? I used to work in a manufacturing company (long time ago), and there were different model numbers to identify that. This is why I'm asking the question.

Comment: they might very well, but that necessitates the user to create various products that do not matter. He just should be able to tick the various colours his device comes in and then map some repairs to either all of these colours or only some.

Comment: Did any of the effort or time I spent help at all? I'm thinking of not helping people as much on stackoverflow...

Comment: HI Alvin, actually no, the answer wasn't addressing the problem that I have. But I admit the question may have been confusing. I don't necessarily get it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on a real world repairing scenario, where one might change the color of the device by changing body, You might want to maintain additional 3 entity instead of one association `devices_colous_repairs` :

1. `device_attributes` (Many-To-One with device)
2. `device_repair_attrbutes` (Many-To-One with repair ids only if the attribute changed in repairing process.
3. Additional `repair_billing` to store bill cost as per standard / attrib change. (Many-To-One with repair ids with optional foreign key with `device_repair_attrbutes` where applicable.

Just a suggestion to normalize the data.

Comment: Thanks! However there will be no need to change the colour. What I now wonder is how I define such a triple join table in symfony mapping?

Comment: The 3rd entity can have association to other 2 entities. This way you can have your data normalized and associated with price.

Comment: so I should set two target entities in the mapping annotation? I don't seem to find any code samples online that make a three-column join table. Or should I work with table inheritance or something?