# Symfony/Doctrine: access to the join tables?

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

In order to circumvent [a problem I had with variations of entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38624790/symfony-doctrine-variations-of-entities) the dirty way, I'm trying to constrain the number of colours available for a device repair. The available colours must not exceed the colours available for the device.

So I have:

**Device.php**

This maps the device to the colours and the repairs available for this device.

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Repair", mappedBy="device", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $repairs;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Color", inversedBy="devices")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="devices_colors",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="device_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      ) 
 */
private $colors;
```

**Color.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Device", mappedBy="colors")
 */
private $devices;
```

**Repair.php**

This maps a repair job to a device but also to a colour.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Device", inversedBy="repairs")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="device_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $device;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Color")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="repairs_colors",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="repair_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="color_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      ) 
 */
private $colors;
```

**RepairType.php**

Point here is to:
map this field 'colors' to the colours available in the `Color` Entity but limit these choices to what is available for this instance of `Device`

```
   ->add('colors', EntityType::class, array(
              'label'=>'Kleuren',
              'class'=>'AppBundle:Color',
              'choice_label'=>'name',
              'choice_value'=>'id',
              'multiple'=>true,
              'expanded'=>true,
              'query_builder'=>function (EntityRepository $er) use ($device) {
                          return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->join('AppBundle:Device','d')
                                ->where('d.id = :device')
                                ->setParameter('device', $device);
                    }
              )
        )
```

Because I know that a devices_colors join table is created, I can achieve the desired result through the following MySQL query directly on the server:

```
SELECT c.name FROM colors c LEFT JOIN devices_colors d ON (d.color_id=c.id) WHERE d.device_id = 1
```

However, my attempts above in RepairType do not achieve the same results. I always get *all* the colours available, not just the ones that have been set on `Device`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. First, I made the ManyToMany relationships (between Color and Repair, and between Color and Device) bidirectional by adding the properties `devices` and `repairs` to the `Color` entity.

Next, I wrote my query_builder attribute as such:

```
              'query_builder'=>function (EntityRepository $er) use ($device) {
                          return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->join('c.devices','d','WITH','d = :device')
                                ->setParameter('device', $device);
                    }
```

That ended up working fine-ish. But it feels like a dirty hack for the problem I had.